# How Boolean constructors can cause performance issue?

Tags: java, constructor, boolean

I am trying to run the code inspection provided in the IntelliJ on my code and it reported performance issue on calling `new Boolean("true")`.
The description in IDE is given as

> Reports any attempt to instantiate a new Boolean object. Constructing
>   new Boolean objects is rarely necessary, and may cause performance
>   problems if done often enough.

Want to understand how or why this statement may cause the performance issue?

Comment: Well, why do you specifically need a new instance? It can literally only take two values so what's the point of having it in multiple instances. You're just allocating more objects.

Comment: Refer http://www.programmr.com/blogs/two-things-every-java-developer-should-know-about-booleans

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, well, I can change it to primitive data type, but keen to understand why or how it can hit the performance

Comment: I just told you -- because you're allocating a new object rather than re-using existing ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call `new Boolean("true")` a million times, you are creating million `Boolean` objects. Instead you can use `Boolean.valueOf("true")` which will reuse the same `Boolean` object (or just use the primitive value `true` and let the compiler handle the boxing for you).

Comment: Well, it is just the overhead of creating objects right? No other specific reason for performance hit, I guess...

Comment: @G.S Creating many unnecessary objects may cause a performance hit (both in terms of the memory they would occupy, the time it would take to execute the Boolean constructor multiple times, and the extra work for the garbage collector, releasing all these objects).